# How do I use variables in less with the Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, less, asset-pipeline

I am converting a number of less files into a rails app, and running into problems with the processing of variables and other less features.

I require my assets in application.css, but when viewing the page see the following error:

```
Less::ParseError: variable @light-border is undefined
  (in tokens.css.less
Served asset /tokens.css - 500 Internal Server Error
```

I have a less file that defines all my variables and several other files that define various mixins.

The problem also seems to affect the mixins - looks like the less files are being processed individually, but not as a single context  ... hence the variable and mixin errors. Individual files will render, but not include the various components and variables.

Is there a trick to getting this working in Rails?

Comment: I added the less-rails gem and it seems to work now. I think the asset pipeline doesn't actually support more than rudimentary less use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the less-rails gem and it seems to work now. I think the asset pipeline doesn't actually support more than rudimentary less use.